# Expected Value & Variance Question

Tags: probability, variance

Suppose x and y are random variables such that E(xy)=0. Suppose also each of x and y has mean 2 and variance 3. Find the variance of x+y.

 
I understand var(x+y) = var(x) + var(y) if E(xy) = E(x)E(y) 
Although, that is not the case due to 1x1 does not equal 0. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: So what's the definition of variance in terms of expectations?

Comment: Would it be the npq formula? But what would n be in this scenario. My textbook does a horrible job in explaining things clearly

Comment: @Lil B there is no indication that the random variables are binomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$, then $Var(X+Y) = E[(X+Y)^2] - [E(X+Y)]^2$.

Figure out $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$ and try applying my hint making sure to use the linearity of the expectation operator.

Comment: @LilB: Great! If you found my answer to be helpful be sure to accept it (Same goes to your other questions as well).

Comment: How do I accept it? I'm new to this

Comment: @LilB: There should be a checkmark towards the left of my answer. Just click that to accept it. Similarly for your other questions.